# Laravel 4 / 5: Make `return Model` automatically use HTML view

Tags: php, laravel, view, model

Please pardon me for not knowing what the terminology of what I'm asking for is. I don't quite know what you'd call it so bear with me.

In Laravel 4 or 5, is there some way to set a default template for an Eloquent Model? For a long time, I've been writing lines like this: (just using book system as example)

```
$book = Sentry::getUser()->books()->find(14);

return View::make( "books.show" )->withBook($book);
```

Is there any way that I can make `return $book;` expand into `return View::make( "books.show" )->withBook($book);` ?

Comment: let's say it is possible. but how laravel will know whether you are returning a variable or you returning the whole template?you need to tweak a whole lot of core files to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking makes sense. However, it doesn't really fit with Laravel's view of the world -- so keep in mind you're sort of striking out on your own.

When you

```
return View::make( "books.show" )->withBook($book);
```

from a route closure or controller action, Laravel treats **anything** returned as a view.  This include regular strings -- i.e., you can do something like

```
return '<p>Foo</p>';
```

and Laravel will render the HTML fragment.

If you try this with a regular PHP object,

```
$o = SomeObject;
return $o;
```

you'll see an error something like this

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

This error happens because Laravel has tried treating the returned object as a string, and *PHP has no default way of rendering an object as a string*.

What PHP **does** have is a way for you, (the programmer), to tell it (PHP) how PHP should render an object if some code (Laravel) treats that object as a string. If you add a `__toString` method to any object, then PHP will use this method to render a string for the object.  Try the following small program

```
<?php
class SomeObject
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'I am a rendered SomeObject';
    }
}
$object = SomeObject;
// cast the object as a string ("treat" above)
echo (string) $object;
```

So -- this means you can, in any object, embed the logic for rendering a view.  Assuming your book class is named `Book`, try the following

```
class Book
{
    //...
    public function __toString()
    {
        return View::make( "books.show" )->withBook($this);
    }
}
```

and then in your route closure/controller action

```
$book = Sentry::getUser()->books()->find(14);

return $book;
```

One thing to keep in mind -- since there can only be **one** `__toString` definition, if you're extending classes that implement `__toString`, you may break someone else's functionality.  To avoid that try using some sort of conditional rendering.

Hope that helps!

**Update**.  Per the comments below. I can't speak to the Accepts header, although my instincts say Laravel doesn't do this as there's not a culture in PHP of looking at the Accepts header.  I could be wrong.  As for using it yourself in `__toString`, I'd nix that as well -- if a user is using your object during an Accepts JSON request, but needs to render it as a non JSON string for some reason, your code would interfere with that.  Better to give you object rendering contexts, and then the people who render your object choose how it renders in the route closure, controller action, or a "IoCrewrite" of the rendering methods themselves.

Comment: That's pretty cool. For some reason, I thought Laravel looks at the `Accepts` header and automagically figures out what to return, whether it be JSON or the View Object. Seeing you have a lot of experience, do you think it'd be safe to override the `__toString()` method only if the right `Accepts` header is present?

Comment: @Goldentoa11 Updated question with some additional thoughts.  Good luck!